# Highlight the cells in different color if not exact dup

Tags: pandas, pandas-styles

I have this dataframe.
If the **Description** is the same then the job entry should be exactly the same.

```
mycol = ['Title', 'Location', 'Company', 'Salary', 'Sponsored', 'Description']
mylist=[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd2', 'e', 'f'),
('g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l' ),
('g1', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l' ),
('n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'),
('n1', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns = mycol)
```

I will like to highlight the differences in yellow background as shown in this image...
[image]

Is it possible in pandas?

Or I can export in excel and process it using VBA. I am trying to achieve this in pandas and then export to excel along with formatting.

---

Update:

Someone suggested to use this:

```
# Select all Columns but Description
cols = df.columns.symmetric_difference(['Description'])
# Clear All columns where Description is duplicated
df.loc[df['Description'].duplicated(), cols] = np.nan
# Fill foward over the blanks
df = df.ffill()
```

But it will replace the values and not highlight it.

Comment: I don't know that it's necessary to take my misunderstanding of your question and add the content of my deleted answer...

Comment: Your answer is helping to achieve the results. I can create a new dataframe based on your answer then compare with original and highlight the differences. That will not be 100% correct, but very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can clear the rows where the description is [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), then use [`groupby ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) to fill the values forward per Description:

```
mask = df.copy(deep=True)
# Select all Columns but Description
cols = mask.columns.symmetric_difference(['Description'])
# Clear All columns where Description is duplicated
mask.loc[mask['Description'].duplicated(), cols] = np.nan
# Fill foward over the blanks
mask = mask.groupby(df['Description'].values).ffill()
```

`mask`:

```
  Title Location Company Salary Sponsored Description
0     a        b       c      d         e           f
1     a        b       c      d         e           f
2     g        h       i      j         k           l
3     g        h       i      j         k           l
4     n        o       p      q         r           s
5     n        o       p      q         r           s
```

---

This can then become our point to compare against:

```
styles = (
    # Remove Where values are incorrect
    mask.where(mask.ne(df))
        # Back fill per group
        .groupby(df['Description'].values).bfill()
        # Anywhere values are not null
        .notnull()
        # Replace booleans with styling
        .replace({True: 'background-color: yellow;', False: ''})
)

df.style.apply(lambda _: styles, axis=None)
```

[image: styled table]

---

[`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`groupby bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-bfill) give us:

```
mask.where(mask.ne(df)).groupby(df['Description'].values).bfill()
```

```
  Title Location Company Salary Sponsored Description
0   NaN      NaN     NaN      d       NaN         NaN
1   NaN      NaN     NaN      d       NaN         NaN
2     g      NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN
3     g      NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN
4     n      NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN
5     n      NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Then [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) allow styles to be set:
`styles`:

```
                       Title Location Company                     Salary Sponsored Description
0                                              background-color: yellow;                      
1                                              background-color: yellow;                      
2  background-color: yellow;                                                                  
3  background-color: yellow;                                                                  
4  background-color: yellow;                                                                  
5  background-color: yellow;
```

Remember to write [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html) from the Styler object not the DataFrame:

```
df.style.apply(lambda _: styles, axis=None).to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

Comment: I do not want to replace the values. I need to highlight in different color.

Comment: Let's try this instead @shantanuo

Answer (score 0):

Someone has suggested this answer.

```
mask = df.copy(deep=True)
# Select all Columns but Description
cols = mask.columns.symmetric_difference(["Description"])
# Clear All columns where Description is duplicated
mask.loc[mask["Description"].duplicated(), cols] = np.nan
# Fill foward over the blanks
mask = mask.groupby(df["Description"].values).ffill()
```

Use the mask dataframe to compare with the original and then apply style.

```
styles = (
    # Remove Where values are incorrect
    mask.where(mask.ne(df))
    # Back fill per group
    .groupby(df["Description"].values).bfill()
    # Anywhere values are not null
    .notnull()
    # Replace booleans with styling
    .replace({True: "background-color: yellow;", False: ""})
)

df.style.apply(lambda _: styles, axis=None)
```

This is working correctly as expected.